# TinyMCE editor not working after getting appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, tinymce-4

I use TinyMCE in one of my website and I need to change a `<div>` to another parent without losing the input of the textarea(TinyMCE Editor) inside the `<div>`. I tried using appendTo but not working. 
Here's what I tried https://jsfiddle.net/y6172pua/

Is there any solution?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AppendTo accepts HTML, not an element. For `appendTo` try with this

```
$($('#z1').html()).appendTo('#t2');
```

You can try simple with `append`

```
$('#t2').append($('#z1'));
```

The problem would be that the editor does not work afterwards because it was not initialized. You should add another box to the second div, intialize the TinyMCE editor on it, get the content from the first one and add it to the second one.

You could try this: https://jsfiddle.net/yomisimie/y6172pua/1/